# pdo::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: name or service not known in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

estoy subiendo mi sitio web al servidor y al momento de loguearme me vota este error. 
tengo una pagina conexion en el cual detallo toda la configuracion

```
define('URL', 'https://www.aynii.pe/');
define('APLICATION', 'aplication/');
define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOST', 'aynii.pe');
define('DB_USER', '');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'aynii_db');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('HASH_PASSWORD_KEY', '@nexus and artic fox Systems and Information Engineer@');
define('DEFAULT_CONTROLLER', 'login');
```

y la recibo en la clase DataBase

```
public function __construct($DB_TYPE,$DB_HOST,$DB_NAME,$DB_USER,$DB_PASS,$OPCIONES)
{
    parent:: __construct($DB_TYPE.':host='.$DB_HOST.';dbname='.$DB_NAME,$DB_USER,$DB_PASS,$OPCIONES);
    parent:: setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
```

no logro encontrar el error ya que hay momentos en que me sale el error y otros en que ingresa normal

Comment: ¿Por qué usas ese código tan raro para conectar? ¿Por qué no creas una instancia de PDO [como muestra el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php), pasándole los parámetros necesarios? Ese error suele ocurrir cuando la cadena de conexión tiene algún error, o sea esto: `$DB_TYPE.':host='.$DB_HOST.';dbname='.$DB_NAME,$DB_USER,$DB_PASS,$OPCIONES` debes revisarlo todo y verificar que es correcto.

Comment: es un framework que trae por defecto esta conexion, solo reemplace los valores

Comment: Revisa todas las variables, algo hay mal en ellas. En el enlace de mi primer comentario el Manual de PHP explica la forma correcta de escribir los valores de conexión. Por ejemplo: `'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', $usuario, $pwd` donde `prueba` debe ser el nombre de la base de datos, `$usuario` el usuario, y `$pwd` la contraseña. Los parámetros deberían ir en ese orden y yo usaría un `new PDO(...)`, no sé por qué usar  `__construct` , realmente no entiendo por qué ni para qué.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé a qué se debe que tu clase tenga *un constructor que invoca a otro constructor*.

Si quieres implementar una clase utilitaria para manejar tus conexiones, simplemente puedes hacerla que extienda de `PDO` y usar el constructor de `PDO` para crear la instancia de la conexión.

**Por seguridad**, las credenciales de conexión no deberían existir definidas en constantes no importa donde. Conviene que sean miembros privados de la clase, o, para más seguridad, guardarlas en un archivo de configuración que esté protegido e incluso aislado para otros usuarios con menos privilegios.

Veamos un ejemplo donde las credenciales de conexión existen como miembros de la clase.

Propondría una clase parecida a esta:

```
<?php

class DataBase extends PDO
{
    private $pdo;
    private $dbtype="mysql";
    private $host="localhost";  //El host suele ser este, no el nombre de dominio
    private $dbname="aynii_db";
    private $dbcharset="utf8";
    private $usr="";
    private $pwd="";

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Connect();

    }

    private function Connect()
    {
        $host=$this->host;
        $dsn = $this->dbtype.":host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->dbname.";charset=".$this->dbcharset;
        $arrOptions = array(
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        try 
        {
            $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->usr, $this->pwd, $arrOptions);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            error_log($this->error = $e->getMessage(),0);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Aquí pasamos todas las opciones en el constructor mediante `$arrOptions`, de ese modo evitamos seguir manejando el objeto una vez creado. Además incluimos la opción `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` en `FALSE` para impedir preparaciones emuladas que pueden ser explotadas por usuarios mal intenciones para intentar emular consultas preparadas e inyectar código malicioso.

### Modo de uso

La clase se usaría así simplemente:

```
$db=new Database();
```

Y ya tendrías un `$db` una instancia de la conexión, sin tener que estar haciendo trasiego de credenciales.

Comment: pero es que mi sitio web esta en un hosting no esta localmente por eso le pongo aynii.pe y como explico funciona por momentos sin ningun tipo de problemas y por momentos me sale ese error

Comment: No hay problema, lo puedes cambiar entonces, eso es lo de menos. Aunque yo también tengo el sitio alojado en un hosting y me funciona con `localhost`.  La respuesta trata de explicar una forma más conveniente de implementar tu clase.

Comment: revisando revisando me doy cuenta que el mismo error en mi otro sistema que funcionaba normalmente hasta que se actualizo mi servidor virtual, entonces la falla es en el servidor(CENTOS 6.10)  al parecer tiene conflictos o algo en php.ini se cambio con la actualización

Comment: ¿Probaste con localhost y usando el código como lo pongo en la respuesta? Ese tipo de errores suele ocurrir cuando se escribe mal el nombre del host o cuando hay algún error en la cadena de conexión.

Comment: bueno desde que le puse localhost hasta ahora no me bota ese error de nuevo parece que si fue la solución :D